# "No Bluetooth Adapter Found" error on an ASUS K53E

Tags: bluetooth

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit os on my ASUS k53E. I cannot get bluetooth to work, I see that it says "No Bluetooth Adapter Found". I have an Atheros Bluetooth adapter, could you please help me how to get this fixed.

Comment: Please open a terminal, run `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 -Fe Atheros`, and add the output to your question.